# Custom nodes via Python?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I read about node groups as a way to develop custom nodes via using existing nodes in Blender.

However, I was wondering if it is possible to write a custom node e.g. a custom geometry node, from scratch purely via Python and the Blender API and add custom attributes?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem possible at the moment. All geometry nodes and shader nodes are written in C/C++.

Comment: you can do so with animation nodes. That's only one reason why this add-on is just amazing.

Comment: @BlenderUser123 if I were to go via C/C++ (and prepared to do a full source build of Blender) do you have a rough idea where in the blender source tree I should start looking at ?